# Can optimal control be used to obtain a desired result?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, control-theory, optimal-control, biology

I am pretty new to the theory and application of optimal control. However, I am curious as it is not mentioned in the textbook that I use. Is it possible to optimize $u(t)$ such that we can obtain a desired (forced) result?

1. For example, if I have a system $x'(t) = g(t,x,u)$ and I want to vary $u(t)$ to force $x(t)$ to move along a path $\bar{x}(t)$ over $t\in[t_0,t_1]$, how should I go about doing so?
2. Furthermore, if the problem is discrete $\bar{x}(t_n)$, where $t_n$ is the time point, how should I go about doing so?

Any references, especially with application to biology, would be appreciated!

Comment: How is this about optimal control? What is being optimized? The question you ask is what birthed control theory itself — design an input such that the state follows a desired trajectory. If you want to go further, you should provide details about $g$ and $\tilde x$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I apologize. I self-study control theory from a textbook by Lenhart and Workman, which is very introductory and applied, so I am not aware of the development of optimal control. I am trying to apply it to my medical research and I find certain pieces of information never stated in the text. As I am unfamiliar with the field, I cannot word my question precisely. I will attempt to describe the applied problem in a future post. But I think the mention of the dynamic programming by Renard maybe what I am looking for. I'd truly appreciate it if you could give some references.

Comment: Only serious application of control theory to medicine I recall is [this one](https://control.ee.ethz.ch/research/applications/anesthesia.html). Please edit your answer and provide details on $g$. Linearity, continuity, smoothness... these things matter, and without more information it's hard to say something useful.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, consider an objective function like
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1}(x(t)-\bar{x}(t))^2 dt,
$$
so you are minimizing the squared deviation from the preferred path, subject to $x'(t) = g(t,x,u)$, presumably given $x_0$.  Then your Hamiltonian is
$$
H(x,u,\lambda,t) = (x(t)-\bar{x}(t))^2 - \lambda(t) g(t,x,u).
$$
At this level of generality, Pontryagin's necessary conditions are not sufficient, and you would have to pick a law of motion for the state variable or sufficient assumptions that you could check the second-order conditions for an optimal control problem (Arrow or Mangasarian concavity of the Hamiltonian).

2. In discrete time, you would use Dynamic Programming instead of optimal control.  You generate a Bellman equation, 
   $$
   V_t(x_t) = \min_{u_t} (x(t)-\bar{x}(t))^2 + V_{t+1}(x_{t+1})
   $$
   subject to $x_{t+1} = g(x_t, u_t, t)$.  You start at $t_1$ and work backward, using the values $V_{t+1}(x_{t+1})$ that you have already computed and minimization of the $t$-period problem to determine $V_t(x_t)$, until you get back to date zero.  There are dozens if not hundreds of introductory books on this topic.

You might need to introduce a cost function for $u(t)$ to ensure that the solution isn't trivial, like "set $x(t)=\bar{x}(t)$".
In